# Is there a programming language supports parsing customized DSL?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

As a programmer, I have to write DSL from time to time. Mostly, they are written in a "host" programming language, in a form of strings or function calling chain. For example, when writing database-relative code, I have to concatenate SQL for querying. If I decide to use a ORM framework like hibernate, usually I will chain functions to define my query conditions, which can be regarded as another form of DSL.

In many cases, it is acceptable to write DSL inside a host language, but if the DSL become complicated, it will guadually loss its readability. Since no matter how, in-host DSL has to comply with the host language's syntax, some additional things have to be added to the DSL, like braces/brackets/parentheses, which doesn't convey any meanging but produces noises.

Is there any solution about this problem? I think the answer is yes - but partially. We can observe that many languages support "templated string", and JSX, a enhanced JavaScript, supports HTML template embedding. But all these solutions are only for curtain particular DSL. As far as I known, there isn't a language provides a general mechanism on dealing this problem. But there are so many programming languages in the world, and new programming languages are introduced oftenly. This makes me wondering, Are there some less-known languages 
 allow people to write DSL freely, without considering the host language's syntax? For example, a language with a DSL-parsing-system, which is able to analyze a DSL as long as you install a parser of that DSL.

Comment: I would guess not.  A programming language not only has to deal with DSL syntax, but also deal with DSL semantics.  The only place I could type pure DS:L was in a particular relational database's dashboard application.  I have used translators that add the syntax characters to DSL for the particular language.

Comment: the question reminds me of the VS DSL tools/SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/overview-of-domain-specific-language-tools  did you mean something like that? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/the-visual-studio-modeling-sdk-is-now-available-with-visual-studio-2017/